# use bash script to remove tracking from google scholar links into non tracking links for wget

Tags: bash, sed, wget

I Get regular google scholar emails. I am trying to make a simple script that lets me download the pdfs / articles, without google tracking me via their urls.

Up till this point I have been copy pasting the links I want to download into a markdown file editor that I pretty much always have open, then I use a bash script that converts the markdown file to a txt file that wget can parse. the bash script i normally run (via a keyboard shortcut) is:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ~/wgetdl
sed 's/.*(\(.*\))/\1/' markdowntowget.md > wgetme.txt
torify wget wgetme.txt
```

this works great when I am just browsing the internet and want to "highlight with mouse, copy, paste, download all the links". but for google scholar links I also need to modify the links themselves.

so, in a nutshell, need to modify above script so that it removes from the beginning of every line:

```
https://scholar.google.com/scholar_url?url=
```

and everything that comes after this in the line:

```
&hl=en&sa=X&d=
```

without touching the rest of the url, and I do not know how to do that. Anyone know the simplest way to do so?

additionally, any suggestions for software (that runs over tor) which would enable me to skip all this would be fantastic. The goal here is to weekly download a bunch of new google scholar results for a specific search term in a form I can read offline without google tracking me, like how you can use calibre to schedual downloads of news. I'm running debian10.

Comment: Can you please post a list of typical links to parse so that regex can be checked.